# Prove function is injective, but not surjective

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

> Prove that the function $f(x) = x^2$ for $x\in \mathbb N$ is injective, but not surjective.

I know that injective means that $f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y$, and
surjective means that for $f(x)=y$. So using this information, how would I prove this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that $f$ is NOT surjective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1121699/prove-that-f-is-not-surjective)

Comment: Injective:  if $x^2=y^2$ then $(x+y)(x-y)=0$ so ...;    Surjective:  is there $x\in\mathbb N$ such that $x^2=2$?

Comment: How is x^2 not subjective?

Comment: @Anonymous For what value $x\in \mathbb N$ is $f(x) = 3$?

Comment: You have not specified a codomain.

Comment: x is all natural numbers in the set.

Comment: As @N.F.Taussig noted, your definition of $f$ is technically incomplete. It is important to specify both what set $f$ 'takes inputs from' and what set $f$ 'produces elements from. If $f$ where given as a function $f:\mathbb N \to A$ where $A=\{ n^2 \mid n \in \mathbb N \}$, then $f$ **would** be surjective.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you mean $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ given by $x \mapsto x^2$ is injective and not surjective.

To show it is not surjective, **hint**:

Can you find a natural number that isn't a square of some natural number?

To show it is injective, if $x^2 = y^2$ we have $x = y$ or $x = -y$, can you continue from here?

Comment: So like numbers like 3, 5, and 7?

Comment: @Anonymous those are examples yes. Do you understand why that shows the function isn't a surjection?

Comment: Wouldn't x  = -y not make it injective?

Comment: @Anonymous what is our domain?

Comment: all natural numbers

Comment: @Anonymous I asked that in order to encourage you to think - if $x^2 = y^2$ and both $x,y$ are natural numbers, what can we say about $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give a counter-example here. Consider the number $y=17 \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $x^2=y \Rightarrow x^2 = 17 \Rightarrow x = \pm\sqrt{17} \notin \mathbb{N}.$ You have found a $y$ such that $x \notin \mathbb{N}$ for $f(x)=y$.  Therefore, $f$ is not surjective.